# Scale divs height pure CSS

Tags: html, css, scale, aspect-ratio

I need to scale the height of divs.

**How it should work**

- The divs should scale, keep current aspect ratio
- The width should be 100px always
- The height should scale in propotion to the 100px width
- I added some example width and height in the code
- Add more HTML + CSS if needed

**Example**

A div block is originally 300px x 600px. When fit the width of 100px it will be 100px x 200px.

**The result**

The result will be divs equally wide but they will be different height, some taller than others.

https://jsfiddle.net/80pk066L/5/

**Notes**

If it whould be an image it would contain aspect ratio when setting width to 100%, but this is not an image. It is a div.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="scale1"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale2"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale3"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale4"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale5"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    /*REMOVE HEIGHT AND WIDTH HERE, JUST DECORATION
    Width should always be 100px
    Height should be whatever, can be larger than 100px
    */
}

.scale1 div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}

.scale2 div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.scale3 div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.scale4 div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
}

.scale5 div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Each `li` forms a 100px square, and has a child `div` of a certain aspect ratio, and you want the child `div` to fit in the `li`?

Comment: For one, you should remove "`div`" in your scale definitions - it is implied by the dot.  I'm not sure what you mean by scale... if you want height of 200 and width of 100, why not set that?

Comment: @MarcAudet No, I should probably edit my question. A div can be 100x200, 100x40 but NEVER like 200x100 or 300x500. Width should always be 100px. Height can be whatever.

Comment: So just don't set a width for your divs, then, nor a height for your list items.

Comment: then remove height from li will give you the desired output right?

Comment: @steveklein div is a child of the .scale1, not the same element. The second. My sizes are generated as blocks, larger blocks than 100px. They need to scale to fit. The height need to have the right aspect ratio. Later on I also will make it responsive. They need to scale again at that time.

Comment: @shaggy A div block of the size 300px x 600px would scale down to 100px x 200px. Therefor I can't just remove someting. If I had an image it whould keep aspect ratio, but this is a div.

Comment: @Aru Look at my answer to shaggy, then you might see that I can't do that.

Comment: I think I get you know and have posted an answer below.

Comment: if the divs will have arbitrary dimensions it cannot be done with just css (*you need to somehow calculate their ratio*). If their dimensions are from a specific list (*predefined ratios*), then you could use the ratio trick (*with `padding`*) and force their width to be 100% of container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bottom padding trick to force a responsive aspect ratio on each individual element. You'll have to calculate the padding-bottom manually of each element, as a percentage of the height to width ratio.

```
.scale1 div {
    padding-bottom: 166.667%;
}

.scale2 div {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.scale3 div {
    padding-bottom: 150%;
}

.scale4 div {
    padding-bottom: 120%;
}

.scale5 div {
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/80pk066L/9/

If you want content in each element, though, they have to be wrapped within an absolutely positioned child element — that is because if they are not taken out of the document flow, the content height will add on to the bottom padding, therefore skewing the aspect ratio:

```
li div {
    position: relative;
}
li div span {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/80pk066L/10/

If using CSS to specify the aspect ratio is too tedious, you can programatically do this using JS. I understand that you might not want to achieve this using JS, but this might be more efficient if you have large number of elements you want to go through. For convenience's sake, I am using jQuery—but any other libraries or even raw JS would work, as long as the same logic is applied:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).children('div').css('padding-bottom', $(this).width()/parseFloat($(this).data('aspect-ratio')));
    });
});
```

I have chosen to store the aspect ratio (in the form of width-to-height) in a HTML5 `data-` attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li class="scale1" data-aspect-ratio="0.6"><div><span>1</span></div></li>
    <li class="scale2" data-aspect-ratio="1"><div><span>2</span></div></li>
    <li class="scale3" data-aspect-ratio="0.667"><div><span>3</span></div></li>
    <li class="scale4" data-aspect-ratio="0.833"><div><span>4</span></div></li>
    <li class="scale5" data-aspect-ratio="2"><div><span>5</span></div></li>
</ul>
```

See proof-of-concept example here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/80pk066L/11/

Comment: It seems to be an correct answer. An extra plus for the JS thing. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying exact widths and heights for the divs, use a combination of `max-width` and `padding-bottom` to achieve this. I've also taken the liberty of converting your layout from using floats to using flexbox instead to save the hassle of having to clear the floats.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
li{
    background:green;
 flex:1 1 calc(33.333% - 20px);
    margin:10px;
    display:block;
    max-width:calc(33.333% - 20px);
}
div{
    background:red;
}
.scale1 div{
    padding:0 0 166.667%;
    max-width:300px;
}

.scale2 div{
    padding:0 0 100%;
    max-width:400px;
}

.scale3 div{
    padding:0 0 150%;
    max-width:200px;
}
.scale4 div{
    padding:0 0 120%;
    max-width:50px;
}
.scale5 div{
    padding:0 0 50%;
    max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="scale1"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale2"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale3"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale4"><div></div></li>
    <li class="scale5"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like it works like expected. Flexbox can be both nice and not so nice. Vote up so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using image placeholders: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80pk066L/8/) if code snippet doesn't work)

```css
ul {
    width: 300px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
li img {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden; /* make sure it's hidden */
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
li div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/*.scale1 div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}
.scale2 div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.scale3 div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
.scale4 div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
}
.scale5 div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
}*/
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="scale1">
        <div></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="scale2">
        <div></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="scale3">
        <div></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="scale4">
        <div></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x60" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="scale5">
        <div></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x75" alt="" />
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- - The divs should scale - The width of the div should be max 100px - The height should scale to what fit max 100px width - Remove li height and width. They are just for decoration -->
```

Comment: You seems to be the first to understand my question correctly. Congrats! However, it was the images I wanted to get rid of in the first place. I should add that to my question. Placing empty images like this means showing them for search engines and not for people. In worst case it can be cloaking a punishment by Google. Except for that it's a clever answer.

Comment: @JensTörnell I'm guessing the only information you have at the beginning is a height and width?

Comment: Yes, I have images where I extract width and height which I set on a div.

Comment: @JensTörnell Then I would suggest that Terry's answer is best :)